# C# method parameter XML-documentation issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xml-documentation

Assume, i have a method which parameters are classes with already defined documentation:

```
/// <summary>
///     Get criterion from table.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="plySide"></param>
/// <param name="criterionType"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public Criterion GetCriterion(PlySide plySide, CriterionType criterionType)
{
   // some code
}
```

PlySide class has it's own xml-documentation:

```
/// <summary>
///     Sides of monoply.
/// </summary>
public enum PlySide
{
   // some code
}
```

As you can see in `GetCriterion` method i didn't define any doc for the `plySide` param tag. 
My question is should i duplicate description of a parameter or should i remove param tags?

Comment: I wouldn't consider it to be duplicated as the developer should always go back to the corresponding file to look at the comments if not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PlySide` documentation will describe *what the type is*.

The `plySide` documentation should describe *what role that parameter plays* within the `GetCriterion` method.

Those will usually be subtly (or not so subtly) different.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't duplicate it but give a context aware description of the parameter. In your case it could be something like this (perhaps it's toally wrong, but I don't know the implementation and intention of your method):

```
/// <summary>
///     Get criterion from table.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="plySide">Monopoly side to get criterion for</param>
/// <param name="criterionType">Criterion to get for the given monopoly side</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public Criterion GetCriterion(PlySide plySide, CriterionType criterionType)
{
   // some code
}
```